# Why does R's 'download_version' (remotes package) always try to download the *.tar.gz file and not the specified Window's binary?

Tags: r, download, package

I'm trying to use the `download_version` function from the [remotes](https://remotes.r-lib.org/reference/download_version.html) package to download several hundred specific versions of `win.binary` packages for off-line work. However, it throws an error when I run the following:

```
download_version(package = "A3",
                 version = "1.0.0",
                 method  = "wininet",
                 repos   = c("https://cloud.r-project.org"),
                 quiet   = FALSE,
                 type    = "win.binary")
```

`Error in utils::download.file(url, path, method = method, quiet = quiet, : cannot open URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/windows/contrib/4.0/A3_1.0.0.tar.gz'`

Any idea why it keeps trying to download the `.tar.gz` file and not the Windows binary, or why it fails to recognize other function arguments like `quiet`?

From the error, I'm surmising the `download_version` function is a wrapper for the `utils::download.file` function - and I have successfully gotten this to work for `download.file` - *and I could be wrong here* - but it does not seem as flexible as `download_version` or the rest of the `remotes` functions.

Thanks for any & all help.

D.

UPDATE 1:

For downloading Windows binary packages, this works for me.

```
download.file(url  = "https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.0/A3_1.0.0.zip",
          quiet    = FALSE,
          method   = "wininet",
          mode     = "wb",
          destfile = paste(fileUpdateDir, "A3_1.0.0.zip", sep = "/"))
```

UPDATE 2:

The package `A3_1.0.0.zip` was used as a test since I know it exists on the CRAN. Since this known package version download failed to work, I knew I had a problem with way my code implemented the function (or the `remotes` package wasn't working correctly).

Comment: `remotes` is not part of R, it's a contributed package.  You should go to https://github.com/r-lib/remotes/issues to report this (these?) bug(s).

Comment: Where do you see those win binary packages?  CRAN doesn't keep binary versions of obsolete packages.

Comment: For `@user2554330`, I updated the post to show binary history - just change the URL to the correct version. Also, yes, I realize `remotes` is a GitHub contribution package, but I don't know if this is a bug or if I'm implementing it incorrectly.

Comment: @user2554330 "CRAN doesn't keep binary versions of obsolete packages." I think it is not an obsolete package: https://cran.r-project.org/package=A3

Comment: For `@user2554330`, post edited for clarification of using the A3 package.

Comment: Why do not try with simple download.packages? " download.packages(pkgs="A3", version="1.0.0", quite=FALSE, type="win.binary", destdir="/tmp")"

Comment: Btw. what is the result of getOption("pkgType")?

Comment: For `@benaja`, using `download.packages(pkgs="A3", version="1.0.0"` works if I only want the latest version. However, if say, i want `xfun_0.6` then I will get `xfun_0.29` - the **latest** package version, not the version I want. Can you be a little bit more specific on your `getOption("pkgType")` question?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241805/discussion-between-benaja-and-dave).

Comment: When I said "obsolete", I meant "versions previous to the latest version".